MergingTwo SQL Queries Select and Count in Single statement
I am Working on project, where I am using two queries to get the result i wanted to process.
Query 1
SELECT MID FROM PMS.MACHINE WHERE STATUS=1 AND MID !=0;

Query 2
SELECT MID,COUNT(STATUS) AS QUEUE
FROM PMS.QUEUE
WHERE STATUS=0
GROUP BY MID
ORDER BY MID ASC;

I wanted to merge this two query into a single query, result should be display as MID from PMS.MACHINE and QUEUE Count From PMS.QUEUE Table.
If there is no count then it will result as zero
these are my current results of query 1

query 2 result

in query 2 if the value zero it returns like this

I want result as like


Merge how? Show us the current two result sets, and also the wanted merged one.

query 1 result will be like
'''
MID
1
2
3
4
5
6
'''
Query 2 result
'''
MID QUEUE
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 3
6 4
'''
it will return as
'''
MID QUEUE
2 2
4 5
5 3
6 4
'''
if mid 1 and 3 are zero
I want to display as like below
'''
MID QUEUE
1 0
2 3
3 0
4 5
5 3
6 4
'''

Show desired output by modifying the question, not in the comments.

Updated my question with results

"in query 2 if the value zero it returns like this"  What does that mean?  Please show the input data you are trying to describe.

Or are you saying that for MID=3 and QUEUE=4, the result should be MID=3 and QUEUE=0?

@dougp I want to display the result as like if mid =1 and queue count is 0 it should display as mid = 1 and queue =0

Please show the data inputs in the question.

And use markdown tables, not pictures.  Pictures can't be read by search engines and they can't be copied and pasted to begin working up a solution.

Your comments are adding confusion.  QUEUE = 0 or COUNT(QUEUE) = 0?    I suspect what you are indicating is that there is no MID=3 where STATUS=0 in PMS.QUEUE.  Please write a more accurate question.  Maybe omitting the source tables and focusing on the query outputs would make the question clearer.

It's difficult to understand your issue, but it looks like you just want a left join to the queue table.

If you feel the source queries are important in the question, and a solution involving using those queries as common table expressions and joining them in a downstream query is unacceptable, post sample data from PMS.MACHINE and PMS.QUEUE, not output data from the queries.  And please post it as text.

Otherwise, the answer is basically select things from query1 left outer join query2

Try this
SELECT m.MID,
(SELECT COUNT(q.STATUS) FROM PMS.QUEUE q
 where q.MID = m.MID) as QUEUE
FROM PMS.MACHINE m
WHERE m.STATUS = 1 AND m.MID != 0


SELECT T1.MID, CASE WHEN T2.QUEUE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE T2.QUEUE END AS QUEUE
  FROM PMS.MACHINE T1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MID, COUNT (STATUS) AS QUEUE
                 FROM PMS.QUEUE
                WHERE STATUS = 0
             GROUP BY MID
             ORDER BY MID ASC) T2
           ON T1.MID = T2.MID
 WHERE T1.STATUS = 1 AND T1.MID != 0


MySQL does not implement FULL OUTER JOIN.
